# Solution of a non-linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find an implicit solution for $
> \vec{F}=\begin{cases}
> \dot{x}=-2x(x-1)(2x-1)\\
> \dot{y}=-2y
> \end{cases}
> $

This is a nonlinear DE, but apparently it is possible to find an implicit solution. One of the other questions was to find a potentialfunction $V(x,y)$ such that $\nabla V(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial V}{\partial x} \\ \frac{\partial V}{\partial y}\end{bmatrix}=\vec{F}$. I found that this function was $V(x,y)=-2(\frac{x^4}{2}-x^3+\frac{x^2}{2})-y^2+C$. I assume I should usethis function to find the solution, but I am stuck finding out how. Could anyone give me a hint here?

Comment: Is it written correctly? As written, the equations are decoupled from each other and can easily be solved.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Thanks for noticing! I didn't see it myself at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{dx}{dt} =-2x(x-1)(2x-1)\\
\frac{dy}{dt} =-2y
\end{cases}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-2y}{-2x(x-1)(2x-1)}$$
This is a separable ODE leading to :
$$y(x)=c_1\frac{x(1-x)}{(1-2x)^2}$$
If we want the functions of $t$, the second ODE gives directly :
$$y(t)=c_2 e^{-2t}$$
$x(t)$ is then obtained in solving for $x$ the quadratic equation :  $\:c_1\frac{x(1-x)}{(1-2x)^2}=c_2 e^{-2t}$
$$x(t)=\frac{1}{2}\pm \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+4\frac{c_2}{c_1}e^{-2t}}}$$